# Not redirecting to dashborad after login in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have just about got my login issue sorted out. But I have only got one issue that when login it is not redirecting to the dashboard page `redirect('dashboard)` it is correct like that but for some reason loads login page.

The sessions say that I am logged on.

**Sessions showing** I have sessions showing on login and dashboard to see weather logged.

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => **************
    [ip_address] => **************
    [user_agent] => **************
    [last_activity] => **************
    [user_data] => 
    [islogged] => 1
    [username] => admin
)
```

**Controller Login**

```
   public function index() {

        $this->load->library('users');

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
              $data['action'] = site_url("login");

              $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);

        } else {

              if($this->users->login() == false) {

                    $data['action'] = site_url("login");

                    $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);

              } else {

                    $data = array(
                          'islogged' => true, 
                          'username' => $this->input->post('username')
                    );

                    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    redirect('dashboard');

              }

        }
  }
```

Comment: and are you actually sure, that the redirect is really reached? I mean did you debug that far? Because the only logically exlanation would be, that the dashboard controller redirects to the login form, or that the login fails.

Comment: I just did more looking around what you said and it was session on dashboard conflicting but not fixed.

Comment: How about you try redirecting to http://google.com? and see.

Comment: @Sobiaholic Please read message above I have fixed it.

Comment: I'm not sure where? but glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have now fixed my own issue on this got every thing working fine now. It was small problem in library file and on login controller.

```
public function index() {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == false) {

                  $data['action'] = site_url('login');

                  $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);

            } else {

                  if($this->users->login() == true) {

                  redirect('dashboard');


                  } else {

                        $data['action'] = site_url('login');

                        $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);

                  }

            } 

      }
```